# Equality of integrals: $ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{1+x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x = 2 \cdot \int_{0}^{1} \frac {1}{1+x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x $

Tags: calculus, integration

In [*Street-Fighting Mathematics*](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/titles/content/9780262514293_Creative_Commons_Edition.pdf) (page 16), Prof. Sanjoy Mahajan states that $$ \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{1+x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x = 2 \cdot \displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} \frac {1}{1+x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x $$ 
I realize this is equivalent to saying that 
$$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} \frac {1}{1+x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x = \displaystyle\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac  {1}{1+x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x, $$ 
but why  is this true?

Comment: The integral is equal to $ \frac{\pi} {2}$. You should stop listening to this Professor...

Comment: @PandaBear I wouldn't question a street fighter.

Comment: Assuming you meant to say $2 \int_{0}^1$, have you learned calculus at all? $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ has a very simple anti-derivative of $\tan^{-1} x$, and simply evaluating the integral will get you an answer easily.

Comment: @user142299 http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/street-fighting-mathematics I was wrong. One should listen to him, but properly!

Comment: @PandaBear Definitely don't question street fighters from MIT :)

Comment: Since there was a vote to close as "unclear", I decided to edit your question, after consulting the book itself. I also added some words to the title (LaTeX-only titles are discouraged for technical reasons), and removed `\displaystyle` from titles, because it breaks formatting of question lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you mean
$$\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{dx}{1+x^2} = 2 \int_0^1 \dfrac{dx}{1+x^2}$$
This is true because
$$\underbrace{\int_1^{\infty} \dfrac{dx}{1+x^2} = \int_1^0 \dfrac{-du/u^2}{1+1/u^2}}_{x = 1/u} = \int_0^1 \dfrac{du}{u^2+1}$$
Hence,
$$\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{dx}{1+x^2} = \int_0^{1} \dfrac{dx}{1+x^2} + \int_1^{\infty} \dfrac{dx}{1+x^2} = \int_0^{1} \dfrac{dx}{1+x^2} + \int_0^1 \dfrac{dx}{1+x^2} = 2 \int_0^1 \dfrac{dx}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: > I assume you mean
$$\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{dx}{1+x^2} = 2 \int_0^1 \dfrac{dx}{1+x^2}$$

- Isn't this what I said? Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: @AhaanRungta Yes, this is because $$\int_1^{\infty} \dfrac{dx}{1+x^2} = \int_0^1 \dfrac{dx}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: @user141421 I don't think you understood. I was quoting *you* - you said "I assume you mean _bla_" even though, I said _bla_.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{1+x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x=\lim_{n\,\to\,\infty}\left({\arctan n}\right)-\arctan0={\pi\over 2}$$

It is not true that $${\pi\over 2}=\pi$$ unless someone made a big mistake and math is all wrong.

Perhaps you meant $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac {1}{1+x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x=\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{1+x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x={\pi\over 4}$$